# Weird filtering/matching behavior in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I have a data.frame with with 31 columns and 31 observation. All data in df is numerical, with positive and negative values.

**From the first 13 columns of my data frame I want to extract the position index of the observation with the max absolute value.**

My code is behaving oddly and I can't figure out why.

The name of the data base is **loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca**

```r
> head(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca)


               PC1          PC2         PC3          PC4         PC5         PC6
Mol_17  0.20956737 -0.148512375  0.24587841 -0.269043967  0.18686684 -0.17759436
Mol_18  0.16206391 -0.137572327  0.37520832 -0.243564027  0.18204151 -0.11839496
Mol_20  0.15833954  0.009470871 -0.04321647  0.094148199  0.36981320 -0.34281987
Mol_23 -0.07904978  0.034748195 -0.13504722 -0.271102820  0.03052371  0.15275525
Mol_30 -0.14805422 -0.333887605 -0.05379184  0.003507335  0.19356645  0.01928621
Mol_33 -0.22142249  0.064829612 -0.16049180 -0.278572239 -0.16350937 -0.16854468
```

I am copying only the first six variables here along with the first 5 observations.

Following is the loop that I am trying and the relative error.

```r
> indexvec <- vector()
> for (i in 1:13) {
    indexvec[i] <- which(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[, i] ==     max(abs(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[ , i])))
  }

Error in indexvec[i] <- which(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[, i] == max(abs(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[,  : 
  replacement has length zero
```

The first thing I did to solve the issue was to look at whether my logic for matching the value I am interested in wasn't good.
Although it may not be pretty, the matching function seems to work.

```r
> which(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[, 1] == max(abs(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[ , 1])))
[1] 15
```

So, the next thing was to change something in the for loop and print the output, and here it gets weird:

```r
> for (i in 1:13) {
    print(which(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[, i] == max(abs(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[ , i]))))
}

[1] 15
[1] 28
[1] 22
[1] 21
[1] 3
integer(0)
integer(0)
integer(0)
[1] 20
integer(0)
[1] 13
[1] 18
integer(0)
```

It seems that the code works on some columns but not on others! And that is weird because here are the values from column 6.

```r
> loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[, 6]
 [1] -0.177594359 -0.118394964 -0.342819874  0.152755248  0.019286210 -0.168544683
 [7] -0.232132045 -0.037674359 -0.164510267 -0.123064519 -0.427363710  0.249120454
[13]  0.189818509 -0.125318890 -0.090817036  0.132368681  0.137849210 -0.179389033
[19] -0.251168502  0.284717837 -0.203070939 -0.025723435  0.161473077  0.072130066
[25]  0.001923286  0.028732683 -0.100890265 -0.091261136  0.216944725  0.085688749
[31]  0.151103335
```

And if I simply look for the value I get the appropriate answer:

```r
> max(abs(loads.P_Y_wolf_df_2012_pca[ , 6]))
[1] 0.4273637
```

Any help to let me understand what the issue is will be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Currently your question focuses more on "your" code which is in my opinion better suited for Code Review. Related: [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/250659).

Comment: Second paragraph of the question: **From the first 13 columns of my df I want to extract the position index of the observation with the max absolute value**.

Comment: Why not use `which.max and somehow combine it with `abs`??

Comment: Is this close to what you need? `apply(df,2,function(x) which.max(abs(x)))`?

Comment: Thanks. which.max seems to work fine, I am still failing to understand why my previous code wasn't working.

Comment: If you want to stick to a for loop(or simply for purposes of understanding), I would suggest that you copy the data structure ie use a data.frame instead of a vector in the loop. However, this will likely be very slow. e.g `res<-df;
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  res[,i]<-which(df[,i]==max(df[,i]))
};
unique(res)` or just: `res<-vector();
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  res[i]<-which(df[,i]==max(df[,i]))
};
res` add the `abs` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` to avoid a loop as follows:

```
apply(df,2,function(x) which.max(abs(x)))
```

If we want to use a loop(not recommended in most cases for computational reasons):

```
 res<-vector()
   for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  res[i]<-which.max(abs(df[,i]))
}
res
```

A variant for loop:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  res[i]<-which(abs(df[,i])==max(abs(df[,i])))
}
res
```

With `sapply`:

```
sapply(df,function(x) which.max(abs(x)))
```

As suggested by @akrun we can also use `max.col`

Results:
`apply`(more informative):

```
PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5 PC6 
  6   5   2   6   3   3
```

Explicit loop:

```
[1] 6 5 2 6 3 3
```

With `max.col`:

```
max.col(t(abs(df)), 'first')
[1] 6 5 2 6 3 3
```

With `sapply`:

```
PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5 PC6 
  6   5   2   6   3   3
```

With `purrr`:

```
purrr::map_dbl(df,function(x) which.max(abs(x)))
PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5 PC6 
  6   5   2   6   3   3
```

Comment: Thanks, added. First time seeing `max.col`